# angularjs - pikaday :manually updated value is not getting updated to the model with pikaday

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive, datepicker, pikaday

I am using pikaday in my angular project to display the date picker. It is working fine if i use the date picker . But when i try to edit the text box manually to enter the date the updated value is not binding to my object.

```
    input type="text" id="dateInput" required pikaday min-date="vm.minDate" max-date="vm.maxDate" format="{{vm.format}}"
 class="txtbox-datepicker div-datepicker" data-ng-required ="true" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 1000, 'blur': 0} }" data-ng-model="vm.myDate" >
```

When I manually pick a date (that is, opening the datepicker and clicking on any date with the mouse), everything works fine but manually updated value is not getting updated to the model.

Any ideas on what may I be doing wrong?

ismyDateValid: function () {
                var todayDate = new Date();

```
            todayDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if ((vm.myDate)) {
                vm.myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
```

this is the validation part

```
var todayDate = new Date();
            todayDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if (!utility.isUndefinedOrNull(vm.myDate)) {
                vm.myDate.toDate().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            if (!utility.isUndefinedOrNull(vm.myDate) && new Date(vm.myDate) myDate todayDate) {
                vm.validmsg = "error";
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Any ideas on what may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the bind variable to the attribute `pikaday`

```
<input pikaday="vm.myDate"> 
Date = {{ vm.myDate.myPickerObject.getDate()}}
```

Comment: if add pikaday="vm.myDate" i get error in console vm.myDate.setHours is not a function

Comment: What's the problem ... ? See here : http://nverba.github.io/pikaday-angular/ - error messages ...?

Comment: here i am doing some validation on my date . (updated in question. So it ended up in error vm.myDate.setHours is not a function . it is failing in the validation code

Comment: So this answers - fixes your initial question - please mark it as  / or upvote to signal that it helped. Thanks

Comment: myPickerObject.getDate() . here waht is myPickerObject

Comment: It's other code breaking it possibly. But the above way is correct anyhow... If you don't answer in a good way - we won't be able to help you.

Comment: i am trying to extract date for comparing it for todays date . Already updated the code in question .This was working if i dont enter date manullay."vm.myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)  is throwing error sayingvm.myDate.setHours is not a function

Comment: Please share relavant code ... The `setHours` you are trying possibly has a wrong date format as base. And has nothing todo with your initial question...

Comment: added the validation part. here vm.myDate is the value getting binded from the UI

Comment: added the validation part. here vm.myDate is the value getting binded from the UI. Comparing the user entered value with todays date (after removing time) and throwing a message.

Comment: JSfiddle n plunker are blocked here :( :(